# Replace empty rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some empty rows in `Bidfloor df_g column` so I want to change they with `floorprice`

the problem is if I do this: `df_g.loc[df_g['Bidfloor'] == 0, 'Bidfloor'] = floorprice` the funtion works but I don't have 0 in the rows, so I'm tring with: `df_g.loc[df_g['Bidfloor'] == '', 'Bidfloor'] = floorprice` to simulate the empty row but I have this error: `TypeError: invalid type comparison`

```
floorprice = 0.2
df_g.loc[df_g['Bidfloor'] == '', 'Bidfloor'] = floorprice
```

Comment: Seems like that's because your comparing an int with a string.  Can we see your actual code?

Comment: I tried with `floorprice` as string too but it didn't work @Acejhm

Comment: Can you try: `df_g.loc[pd.isnull(df_g['Bidfloor']) == True, 'Bidfloor'] = floorprice`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are checking to see if your value is an empty string, where you should be checking to see if it's null.

This will give you the desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
floorprice = 0.2
df_g.loc[pd.isnull(df_g['Bidfloor']) == True, 'Bidfloor'] = floorprice
```

[`pandas.isnull()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) will return `True` if the value is missing.